# UILabel inside UIView produces rounded corner with "square corner"

Tags: objective-c, uiview, storyboard, uilabel

I have an UIView which I created and set background color to white. This view contains UILabel, which is a class called BubbleView. (Sorry I cannot add a picture because you need reputation 10+ :(

PROBLEM:
1. The following code produces a gray Label with rounded corner with gray-border square corner tips. This is because the UIView produces the square corner tips. The UILabel is rounded. Please note that I already set the background of UIView to white.
2. My text string of the UILabel is hiding behind UIView, so it is not displayed.

I'd love to show you pictures, but I am new and I cannot add pictures until I get to 10+ reputations.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdRjy.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCdCV.png

Here is my code for setting the text and the view:

BubbleView:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    const CGFloat boxWidth = self.bubbleWidth;
    const CGFloat boxHeight = self.bubbleHeight;

    NSLog(@"text, width, height: %@, %f, %f", self.text, self.bubbleWidth, self.bubbleHeight);

    CGRect boxRect = CGRectMake(
                                roundf(self.bounds.size.width - boxWidth) / 2.0f,
                                roundf(self.bounds.size.height - boxHeight) / 2.0f,
                                boxWidth,
                                boxHeight);

    UIBezierPath *roundedRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:boxRect cornerRadius:14.0f];
    [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.3f alpha:0.8f] setFill];
    [roundedRect fill];

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                 NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f],
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]
                                 };

    CGPoint textPoint = CGPointMake(
                                    self.center.x+boxWidth/2,
                                    self.center.y+boxHeight/2);
    NSLog(@"text point origin: %f, %f", textPoint.x, textPoint.y);

    [self.text drawAtPoint:textPoint withAttributes:attributes];
}
```

Main View Controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self setText];




}

-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [self setText];


}
- (void) setText
{
    NSString *textR = @"I need this text to show up on autolayout so that i could continue working";


    UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0f];
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(250,9999);
    CGRect textRect = [textR boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}
                                          context:nil];

    BubbleView *hostView = [[BubbleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 160.0f, textRect.size.width+20, textRect.size.height+20)];
    hostView.bubbleWidth = textRect.size.width+20;
    hostView.bubbleHeight = textRect.size.height+20;
    hostView.text = textR;
    hostView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    self.view.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;
    [hostView drawRect:textRect];
    hostView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.detailsView = hostView;

    //self.detailsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    NSLog(@"size: %f, %f", textRect.size.width, textRect.size.height);

    NSLog(@"origin: %f, %f - size: %f, %f, backgroundColor: @%@", self.detailsView.frame.origin.x, self.detailsView.frame.origin.y, self.detailsView.frame.size.width, self.detailsView.frame.size.height, self.detailsView.backgroundColor);

    [self.view addSubview:self.detailsView];
    self.hostSays.text = textR;
    self.hostSays.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view layoutSubviews];

}
```

SOLUTION (ONLY 1 PART): 
OK so I managed to solve half of my problems. I had to add the following code in my BubbleView class (inside - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame). This got rid of the square angles! (I think Wain was the one who suggested this but I might've misunderstood him)...

```
[self setOpaque:NO];
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

So...still have the other part 2 of problem to solve and I'm hoping someone has run into this issue before!

Comment: Why are you adding a subview and using `drawRect`? And you should never call `drawRect` yourself...

Comment: I needed a view because I wanted my UILabel to have spacing all around it. This UIView is the spacing around this should be in the form of rounded corner. I had created a subclass of UIView called BubbleView and overrode the drawRect class. When I didn't put this in, I didn't even get any gray square.

Comment: I didn't say don't have a view. But you should either add subview or use `drawRect`, not both.

Comment: OK I deleted drawRect and just used addSubview, but the result is the same.

Comment: did you ever solve the problem ?

Comment: Yes I did. It was a combination of things. After I set the frame, as Wain has indicated, I had to pull the text to the front of the view I use "bringSubviewToFront". In my code above, I was also drawing the text twice so I had to remove one of them. Thanks so much everyone, I couldn't have done it without you. Sorry I can't even vote on your answers. What a weird thing in StackOverflow!!!

Answer (score 0):

Set the background colour of the view and add the label as a subview. Set the frame to get your required padding. Do not implement `drawRect`.

Now, the view will draw the background colour and the label automatically and the label will draw the text (with its background colour and border settings).

Comment: I did try setting the frame, but since I have autolayout on, it doesn't work :( just added pictures on this post.

Comment: I did have the line to set the view's background color in setText hostView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Comment: I did have the line to set the view's background color in setText hostView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; I also initWithFrame for the BubbleView     BubbleView *hostView = [[BubbleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 160.0f, textRect.size.width+20, textRect.size.height+20)]; --> I think this is correct right? not sure what's happening.

Comment: Yes, but you should add constraints to maintain the margins and stop using `drawRect`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save your coding approach you strongly need to add `[super drawRect:rect]` in your `drawRect:` method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    YOUR CODE
}
```

In this case you will see your text in `UILabel`.

Also you should not call `drawRect:` directly. It will be called automatically in runtime:

```
BubbleView *hostView = 
 [[BubbleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 
                                              160.0f, 
                                              textRect.size.width+20, 
                                              textRect.size.height+20)];
hostView.bubbleWidth = textRect.size.width+20;
hostView.bubbleHeight = textRect.size.height+20;
hostView.text = textR;
//  hostView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
//  self.view.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;
//  [hostView drawRect:textRect];
//   hostView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.detailsView = hostView;
```

[image]

Comment: just added but the result is the same :(

Comment: i've just implemented this code by myself in ios7 simulator. All is fine as you want: no square angles and viewable text in BubbleView.

Comment: That is very interesting. I still didn't get this. It seems like the margins between the text and button is not 10px. I was able to get the text to show up on the rounded UILabel (similar to yours) earlier when I didn't have a view underneath. When I added a view underneath and the UILabel on top of the view, I hit this deadend where the BubbleView is covering the text... Can you put what you have on github? I want to see what you did! Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: You can find my test project [here](https://github.com/iospro/questions-20990266)

Answer (score 0):

I know when I create custom buttons I need to `setMasksToBounds`

```
    + (void) addBorderToButtons:(UIButton *) btn
    {
        // Round button corners
        CALayer *btnLayer = [btn layer];
        [btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [btnLayer setCornerRadius:15.0f];

        // Apply a 1 pixel, black border around Buy Button
        [btnLayer setBorderWidth:1.5f];
        [btnLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    }
```

Setting this changes

[image]

To this

[image]

Comment: I will have to try this tomorrow and will let you know. Thank you. it's 2.45AM where I am..